# Best window AC for high humidity climate suitable for permanent mounting

Tags: air-conditioning

I was thinking about having a carpenter mount a window air conditioner in a room.  But, the problem I always have with window air conditioners units is that the humidity is too high where I live and the unit fills up with water and overflows leaking water onto the interior dry wall.

What’s the best way to solve this problem?  Is there a brand of window mount AC that is suitable to be permanently mounted in a humid climate and won’t start to destroy the walls with water damage after a week of use.

You can’t really tip the air condition over if it’s mounted in a wooden frame by a carpenter can you?

Comment: This is just improper installation - a correctly mounted window air conditioner does not "fill up" in high humidity, it drips water outside the window. But the correct answer to "permanently mounting an air conditoner" these days is to install a minisplit rather than taking up valuable window space. That will have a drain line to take water outside.

Comment: sounds like you might want to run a dehumidifier, even if the AC is properly installed, it will make your space a lot more comfortable.

Comment: Note that a "minisplit" will likely be more expensive than your standard box-store purchased window A/C unit. _However_, that's the short term cost. The long term cost of repairing wall damage from an improperly installed until will likely be _significantly_ higher.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that your prior experience with window mount units may have involved _improperly mounted_ units that are tilted _inside_ the house, allowing water to collect and drain inside? I've used a window AC unit in our house for many summers and have never had or seen signs of a single drip on the inside.

Comment: I did answer your question directly in an answer but I'll add here that I agree with others you should look at mini splits.  They are more expensive than window units, but if you are wall-mounting a window unit you'll be bringing in a carpenter, electrician, and probably painter .... now the extra cost of the mini split doesn't look so bad compared to the much much better experience and it can be done entirely by an electrician with minimal wall damage.

Answer (score 1):

There are AC units designed for through window, or wall use. Get one of those installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you mount a window A/C in a wall you need to mount it tilted slightly downwards towards the outside.  They all have drain holes on the outside side, you just need to make sure the water finds its way there by correct installation.   You may also need to attach a hose to the drain depending on what's below it and whether you want to drip water on it.  Bigger window /Cs will have wall mount kits available to make this easier.

So the answer to your last question is "yes", a carpenter should know how to do what you want.